# How to allow an element to get out of its parent

Tags: html

I have a right-floated div within a container with the width of 960px and I want it to have a bigger width but not allow the scroll to show, here's a picture:

[image]

It's the pink box which has the title "From the journal"

Comment: Are you maybe looking for something like `white-space:nowrap; overflow:hidden`?

Comment: you can use `position:absolute` for achieve this and this will work

Comment: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pW5u3/) - Everything works here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/QBmKm/. It uses `overflow: hidden;`

```
<div class="container">
    ceva
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="left">
            left
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <div class="box">
                ceva
            </div>
        </div>
        <br style="clear: both;">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    ceva
</div>
```

and the css is

```
.container {
    width: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    background: gray;
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.left {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}
.right {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}
.box {
    width: 9999px;
    background: red;
    padding: 50px 0;
}
.wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all i want to say that is very good design :-) 
now as am assuming

**you can use**

```
`position:absolute`
```

for achieve this and this will work

Answer (score 0):

Close the container, create a new div for the row which you want to have different settings and open the container again for the bottom part.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an element to be displayed outside it's parent element, you need to use a negative `margin`.

```
<div>
  <div id="outercontainer">
    <div id="biggerelement">
      asdfasdfasdfasdf
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

with CSS:

```
#outercontainer {
  width: 500px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto; //center the outer container
  border: 1px solid blue; //just to show it
}

#biggerelement {
  margin-left: -50px; //The element will start 50 pixels left from it's parent element
  margin-top: 5px; //...and 5 pixels below the edge of it's parent
  border: 1px dotted yellow;
}
```